# How do I compute an average of calculated averages in MS reportviewer/rdlc?

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I've searched here and elsewhere on the web and have not found this exact problem/solution.

I'm building an rdlc report using the MS reportViewer - the report I'm creating is based on an existing spreadsheet where the average price across 6 months is calculated individually for each month, then the average of those prices is calculated as the 6 month period average price. Whether I agree with that methodology or if it's correct is irrelevant, I just need to know how to get an rdlc to do this.

For example:

Month   Price1  Price2  Delta

May-12  $31.54  $30.03  $1.51

Jun-12  $36.27  $34.60  $1.67

Jul-12  $44.19  $42.00  $2.19

Aug-12  $38.96  $37.06  $1.90

Sep-12  $36.89  $35.08  $1.81

Oct-12  $35.57  $33.97  $1.60

Average $37.24  $35.46  $1.78

(sorry for the lack of a screen snip, I'm new and the system won't let me post an image...)

I've created a tablix that does the monthly averages computation - I use a group in the table to group the 6 months of data by month (and then hide the hourly price data so you only see the month total row) but I'm stuck on how to calculate the bottom row of the table which is the average of each column. (the average of the averages is not the same as the average of all 6 months of prices from the underlying data - that's what I've learned in this process... IOW, that was my first solution :-) )

What I tried to do to get the average of the averages was give the month total cell a name, MonthlyAvgPrice1, then in the bottom row, used this expression:

Avg(reportitems!MonthlyAvgPrice1.Value)

As I kind of expected, this didn't work, when I try to run the report, it gets a build error saying "The Value expression for the textrun 'Price1PeriodAvg.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers."

Hopfully I've explained this well, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!
-JayG

Comment: I never use the AVG function, but for what I can see in the [msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159806%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), you can specify the Scope of your function. The Scope [is explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159673%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: From the data what you have shown is that you need the average of each of these columns in the last row .. is it what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not clear from the question that how are you in particular binding the data to the report items, But from the given information what I understand is that you can 

Try like this:

- Right Click the tablix row and insert a row below
- In the cell where you want to have this **Average of Averages** insert the following expression

  `=Sum(Fields!Price1.Value)/6` 
   
  and similarly insert expression `=Sum(Fields!Price2.Value)/6` 
   and  `=Sum(Fields!Delta.Value)/6` in the other cells where you want to display the Averages

Of Course, you will change the Field names Price1,Price2 etc to the fields that you are getting the values from.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply ciphers, that doesn't quite solve it because there are actaully thousands of price values that are being grouped and averaged by month. Those rows of the table are hidden because I just need the final monthly average in the report. So there is a parent group to group by month, then the hourly details rows (hidden) with a totals row where the monthly averages are computed (visible), then the grand totals row outside the parent group where I'm trying to calculate the average of the monthly averages.

Comment: what I mean by this answer is that you can use the same expressions which you use to get the averages and then do like above `=sum(urexpresssion)/6`, put this in the cell and you should get the results......if it is not clear then you simply right click the cell where there is your monthly average and check the expression, then use same as said above.. u try first, it should work !

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Ciphers, it turns out that the correct calculation is the overall average, so I don't need to figure out how to do the average of averages. Really appreciate you taking the time to reply!